# Hashing with HmacSHA256 returns unexpected result

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, sha256, hmac

I need to sign a message with a MAC using SHA-256 algorithm. I have the code for generating the MAC, however validation on the other end is failing.
I've been told that the value I am calculating is wrong.

Here is my code

```
    public static byte[] calculateMAC(byte[] _aiOutBufferForMacCalculation, String key) {
    try{

        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
        byte[] mac_data=sha256_HMAC.doFinal(_aiOutBufferForMacCalculation);

        String result = "";
        for (final byte element : mac_data)
        {
            result += Integer.toString((element & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Result:[" + result + "]");

        return mac_data;
    } catch (Exception _exception) {
        _exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String key = "7F6D7A688019DC4CA83883F2459E6B389BE99BB63B622A97";
    String cadena = "1800990000014303181112190600048430303030303134370029030003483032001148324830303030303135320008143919751D5EB97C";


    byte[] data_for_mac = hexStringToByteArray(cadena);

    System.out.println(new String(data_for_mac));

    byte[]mac =  calculateMAC(data_for_mac,key);



}

}
```

What I see printed as a result is:
0e01a8a96b30ae0a918865d1cef898ea4f96e18680fa9aae4c5d9902090c2f81

But the expected value is:
7684024da7fe89029965ac037a1ec94b21479c91cd8495e726fec924e84b0773

I used a couple of online tools that allow me to enter an hexadecimal string as inputo to generate the hash. The result is the same as the expected, so I confirmed that mine has a problem.

I don´t know what I might be doing different or wrong,can anyone please help?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `main` function parameters, I'm expecting that key is hex string too. So you need to call `hexStringToByteArray` for it too. `getBytes()` method just return bytes, it will not convert from hex string.

Change `calculateMAC` function to something like this:

```
public static byte[] calculateMAC(byte[] _aiOutBufferForMacCalculation, byte[] key) {
    try{

        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA256");
    ...
    }
```

and you `main` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String key = "7F6D7A688019DC4CA83883F2459E6B389BE99BB63B622A97";
    String cadena = "1800990000014303181112190600048430303030303134370029030003483032001148324830303030303135320008143919751D5EB97C";


    byte[] data_for_mac = hexStringToByteArray(cadena);
    byte[] mac_key = hexStringToByteArray(key);

    // System.out.println(new String(data_for_mac)); <-- what is this????

    byte[] mac =  calculateMAC(data_for_mac,mac_key);
}
```

I tested and with these 2 small changes, you get your expected results.

By the way, I'm expecting that you have surely not posted all important key in this sample code and you are just using a dummy one. :D

Comment: That absolutely solved it! Thank you very much, and yes I used a dummy key I got from a random key generator.